# How to use #include for .S file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, assembly, include, preprocessor, include-path

The #include directive in a .S assembler file in Xcode doesn't seem to use the same header/user search path settings as the .c .cc .cpp .m .mm etc. files do.

Does anyone know where this setting lives? Is this just a bug? Is it perhaps to do with how I format my include path setting: ./../../Some/Path/ that it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. If open the project file in a text editor my ./../../Some/Path/ is missing, and instead there is a previous path I had added years ago (which always worked, and I thought odd that it was missing when I first looked). Adding the include path directly in the file by hand worked.